# Windows Console odd behavior. Console.SetWindowSize bug in c#

Tags: c#, console

I noticed a very odd behavior with windows console.

```
        static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.SetWindowSize(80, 25);
        Console.SetBufferSize(80, 25);

        Console.ReadKey(true);
        Console.SetWindowSize(80, 25);
        Console.SetBufferSize(80, 25);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

The windowsize should not change after ReadKey(), but it does!

Why is this simple code buggy when run in windows' new updated console? It works without issue in legacy console or non-window 10 machines who didnt get an update for their console. This behavior bugs out all of my other console applications. I made a video to showcase this weird behavior: https://youtu.be/ZST-u-LIjQQ

EDIT: Is there a way to force the application in legacy console in code temporarily?

EDIT2: I figured out that in new console, when setting windowsize set the scrollbar is included in the size, so setting something in the last few spaces gets hidden behind the scrollbar. In legacy it is not included, so it displays everything.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: How do i force the application to start in legacy mode in the code itself, but only temporarily?